# Seeing the desktop while in Unity mode in VMWare Fusion?

Tags: windows, virtualization, vmware

When I run VMWare Fusion in Unity mode, is there any way to see the desktop or access the files on the desktop? Or must I switch into Single Window/Full Screen mode?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot view the windows desktop as the "Desktop" in Unity (As @mankoff said, you can open it as a folder). The intention of Unity is to *Run Windows apps "side by side" with Mac apps*. This means the Mac desktop is *the* desktop.

I remember there was an option to "Show taskbar in unity" in a older version. Unable to find it in version 3 (did not look for long, anyway I think this is not very useful)

BTW, the way I use VMWare is only for application installs. All my data still stays on my mac (in a special folder if required) but not inside the VM. Helps me back them up, email them if required (even when the VM is suspended). So I never felt a need to *see* the desktop.

Comment: `Show Taskbar in Unity` is found under the `View` menu. Also `Show System Tray in Unity` option is present. (I have VMWare Fusion 3.1.2)

Comment: @koiyu I see it now. Missed it perhaps because I never felt the need for the view menu in the recent days (got Fusion 3 in Dec), the VM is almost always in Unity.

Comment: note that shared folders under Fusion are maddeningly slow (try using Visual Studio with a non-trivial project stored in a shared folder).

Answer (score 5):

You can view the Desktop as a folder in Windows Explorer.